# Why <td> onclick event not firing in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-table

I have a `<td>`, clicking on that I want display a `div`
here's my code:

```
 <td id="tdmord" style="padding-left: 15px; color: #86A7C5; padding-right: 15px; font family: Arial;
  font-size: small;" onclick="return showdiv1()">
  My Orders
 </td>
```

and here's the JavaScript:

```
function showdiv1 {
        document.getElementById("divmo").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }
```

the problem is the `<td>` is not clickable and I can't click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your showdiv1 is missing this `()`

define showdiv1() like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showdiv1()   {
      document.getElementById("tdmord").style.display="block";
       alert('s');
       return false; 
}
</script>
```

also Id that your function showdiv1 is using is wrong. correct that!!!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `()` for `showdiv1`

```
function showdiv1() {
    document.getElementById("tdmord").style.display="block";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1, was just about to post it. It is not a function if `()` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Working code , There is no need to create extra function for it.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="document.getElementById('abc').style.display='block';">change color</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="abc" style="display:none;">       
    pranay       
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/167/)

---

Error in you code you missed () , updated code is

```
function showdiv1() {
        document.getElementById("divmo").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/168/)